# How to make bootstrap 3RC tabs fade using tab('show')?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, show-hide, fadein, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tabs

I have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/vgarcias/Jp42c/6/).

I was already able to have my tabs to open/close while clicking, but now the fade transition is not working.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="home">
        <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        <p>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid.</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).off('click.tab.data-api');
$(document).on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tab = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var activate = !tab.hasClass('active');
    $('div.tab-content>div.tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.nav.nav-tabs>li.active').removeClass('active');
    if (activate) {
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you require to use tab('show')? Or would you consider just using the markup provided with BootStrap (no javascript required)?

Comment: Whatever works, I mean I'm using tab(show) to open/close de tab content... is there a way to toggle the tab content with just markup?

Answer (score 0):

Your turned off the data api by `$(document).off('click.tab.data-api');` and add a new function. Your function don't handle transitions for fading.

Read the doc on: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs and try to activate the tabs by javascript:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Jp42c/13/